# Как задать размер шрифта относительно ширины родительского блока?

Tags: css

Есть текстовый блок с максимальной шириной 500рх.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24рх;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Можно ли как-то задать размер шрифта относительно ширины родительского блока, чтобы при уменьшении ширины блока менее 500рх шрифт также уменьшался пропорционально ширине?

Answer (score 0):

Да можно, с помощью calc

```
.text {
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin);
}
```

с calc можно делать разные вычисления. Можно почитать тут https://habr.com/ru/articles/310186/  или погуглить(информации полно)
Но если вы имеете ввиду уменьшение экрана, под смартфоны и тд, лучше воспользоваться @media запросами. Можно тут почитать или так же загуглить https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/

Comment: Этот вариант не делает то, что нужно. Шрифт уменьшается даже при ширине больше ширины блока. Нужно, чтобы шрифт уменьшался только тогда, когда ширина окна браузера меньше ширины блока.

Comment: по этому есть @media запросы. Шрифт может в один момент стать слишком маленьким. И под экраны меньше нужно будет думать о другом виде интерфейса

Comment: Именно для этого мне и нужно уменьшать размер шрифта, без медиазапросов. Блок уменьшится с 500px до самого минимума - 320px, и шрифт не сильно уменьшится и будет читаем на мобах.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте медиавыражение с calc.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .text {
    font-size: calc(100vw / (500 / 24));
  }
}
```